# Google Home. Problem regarding configure a Lock device

Tags: iot, google-home, google-smart-home

Intro:

- was created a Google Smart Home project
- was configured a proxy server via ngrok to redirect the Google request to my local machine

I develop an IoT project that has the ability to open/close a lock. I need to implement Google integration to use the Google Assistant to control the user locks. I have implemented OAuth Server for Google. Also I have implemented some controllers to handle Google Action Intents: `SYNC`, `QUERY` and `EXECUTE`. Google send a request with the SYNC intent and App response a payload that contain devices list with specific settings. Instance:

```js
{
  requestId: 'requestIdOfGoogle', // contains in the request body
  payload: {
    agentUserId: 'userId123', // matches user id inside app system
    devices: [
      {
        id: 1,
        type: 'action.devices.types.LOCK', // device type
        traits: ['action.devices.traits.LockUnlock'], // feature that has a device
        name: {
          name: 'Kos Lock'
        },
        willReportState: true,
        roomHint: 'Main Door',
        deviceInfo: { // Test data
          manufacturer: 'smart-home-inc',
          model: 'hs1234',
          hwVersion: '3.2',
          swVersion: '11.4'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then Google send requests to my server with `QUERY` intent to get info about state of a devices, instance

```js
{
  requestId: 'requestIdOfGoogle', // contains in the request body
  payload: {
    devices: {
      1: {
        status: 'SUCCESS',
        online: true,
        isLocked: true,
        // isJammed - Boolean. Whether the device is currently jammed and therefore its 
        // locked state cannot be determined.
        isJammed: false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But after sending a response a test lock isn't configured and a user can't control one with Google Assistant.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBbb3.png)

I have tried to add other traits for a lock but it didn't help me. Also I have the same problem when I try to configure a Door device. But when I send to Google a `Light` device it works successfully. When you use the `LockUnlock` trait then Google Doc recommends to setup **secondary user verification** but it's optional.

I don't understand that do incorrect. If someone faced such a problem and solved it then could you help me, please

Prerequisites:

- use node ^14.0.0
- programming language - `js`

Comment: It looks like it's correctly showing up in the app. Do voice commands not work?

Comment: Voice commands works. But I want to implement touch control from Google Home App. Possible I need to research 'how to setup Google Home App' on user-side. And it will help me solve my problem. But I'm not sure. Thank you 
I will continue my research

Answer (score 1):

[Touch controls](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/touch-controls) are not supported for every device, and locks are not a device type that can be controlled directly. But they will still respond to voice commands.

Comment: I have researched third-party Yale app that have feature to lock/unlock a lock. This app have a touch control to execute a command lock/unlock. But possible Yale app registered a custom device with same a lock icon and add a feature to control a lock from Google Home app. I think that I need to research this way - registering a custom device type

Comment: That's a third-party, which is going to be something that Yale may do for their own devices in their own app but is different than the Google Home app.